# component and directive query by ContentChildren in angular2

Tags: angular

Angular Form let us pretty convenient.So I implement form component with input what I did myself.Thus, I want to set  tag `required` so that I use directive to deal.

After all the thing is done, I got some problem when I want to query every single component which is taged `required`.I set `ContentChildren('required')`, as a results, it only show directive detail without my component.

**directive()**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[isRequired]'
})

class requiredDirective{
...

@HostBinding("class.isRequired") _isRequired = true;

...
}
```

**(FormComponent)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
})

@ContentChildren(requiredDirective)
public InputComponents: QueryList<requiredDirective> = null;
_submit(){
  console.log(InputComponents);
}
```

**FormComponent.pug**

```
ng-content
```

**main-pug**

```
my-form
  input(isRequired)
```

`InputComponents` only display directive detail on console table.Currently,I use `input(#isRequired="")`,and got `ContentChildren('isRequired')`,the value of return is Correct and Clear.
But In my bug , it isn't clear for use which use `#isRequired=""`.Is any clear way to deal this situation?